# Can わけがわからない be used as adjective?

Tags: meaning, words

Excuse my seemingly dumb question. I was reading a fan comment: (please feel free to read just the first paragraph, i just put the rest for some context but it may not be necessary)

```
第40話では、「わけがわからない『好き』」を侑も求めていたのに、 
燈子はそれを知っているなんて「ずるい」と侑はこぼす。 

かつての侑にとって、「好き」、「誰かを特別に思う気持ち」は、どこかから降ってくるものだった。 
まるでそう、このコマで描かれている流れ星のように。 
だからこそ、侑にとっての「好き」は手の届かない「星」としてずっと表現されてきた。 

でも、それは違った、と侑は話す。 
「わたしの『好き』は」「自分で選んで手を伸ばすものだったよ」。 
そして侑は、何度も、何度も燈子を選んできたことを話す。 
「先輩がたくさん好きって言ってくれたから、選べた」と。
```

The わけがわからない in **「わけが わからない『好き』」**  here seems to be describing  『好き』. I know わけがわからない is a set phrase to mean "I don't understand the reason of this", "nonsense" but  I haven't found something in Japanese online dictionaries of an use like this one. In this context, I understand it as "unreasonable" love, or love "that happens without a reason". Is it correct? Can it be used as an adj.?

Answer (score 3):

You can generally use verbs like adjectives in Japanese, like in ｢わからない文章｣.
訳が分からない is no exception, although ｢訳**の**分からない｣ may sound more natural in some sentences.

Edit: A similar example can be found [here](http://kanchigai.biz/%E3%80%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91%E3%81%AE%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E4%BA%8B%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E4%BA%BA%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AB%E5%9B%B0%E3%82%89%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B.html), where 訳の分からない事を言う人 is used.

Comment: Is there a meaningful difference between 訳が分からない and  訳の分からない in particular contexts?

Comment: No difference in meaning afaik, but の is more commonly used in cases like this. I think it is almost only used in this kind of adjectivial sentence. Other examples: 「天気の悪い日」「センスのない男」and so on. Using が in these sentences is not wrong at all though, and you will probably also commonly come across it.

Comment: Korean has a very similar composition, but in Korean a word like "が" is used in that case. So, when I first started learning Japanese (self-study), I had to memorise that I should use "の" instead of "が". But when I watch recent Japanese animations, it seems that I hear "が" more often than "の" for this case. Maybe, in spoken Japanese, younger people began to prefer "が"?